# Repoint website in Azure App Service to Azure static site storage container blob with no downtime

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, azure-app-services, azure-storage

I have a production website in an App Service with 4 custom domains bound to it and two SSLs.

I have a newly developed static website that is deployed to a storage container static site $web blob.

I need to point the domains (and associated SSLs) to the new storage container resource.

### Challenges:

1. Need to avoid ANY downtime
2. So far my understanding is the static site hosting in the storage container only allows for 1 custom domain so need a solution (CDN or Reverse Proxy)?
3. ideally everything is handled in Azure (outside of DNS for the domains, currently 2 A records and 2 CNAME records, DNS can be updated)

Anyone with experience with this kind of scenario who can recommend a path to meetings the above requirements? The solution can include multiple steps, new services configured and anything else that helps overcome the 3 challenges. Thanks!